# Sequential/continuous/continued/parallel addition

Tags: terminology

This may be out of topic... I have post a question in English stack exchange, but there is no answer so far...

I would like to know what's the standard way to say **sequential/continuous/continued/parallel** multiplication or addition for calculation like `3 * 5 * 10 * 2 * 11` or `1 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 100`.

Comment: [Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation): In mathematics, summation is the addition of a sequence of any kind of numbers, called addends or summands; the result is their sum or total.

Comment: And see [Product of a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)#Product_of_a_sequence), but I do not know a single English term for it (we have Produttoria in Italian).